# Filling in hole in bathroom counter tile

Tags: bathroom, tile, countertops

The previous owners drilled a hole in our tiled bathroom counter for a soap dispenser, but they never installed anything. We're not fans of built in dispensers and would like to fill in the hole. Precisely matching the tile isn't a key requirement as we eventually want to completely redo the bath completely. We mostly just want the hole to be covered up (water intrusion isn't a problem). I don't have any spare tiles nor any information on the type of tile used in this project.

Are there any practical options to install some sort of plug that will be fairly unobtrusive and structurally sound?

[image: bottom] [image: bottom]

Comment: Since you're remodeling eventually why not go with a hole cover matching the faucet finish? An invisible patch is going to be a bit more effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to just get a hole plug of the right size that matches your faucet. It'll be noticeable, but it won't look out of place. Your local hardware store should sell them, though if it's an unusual size I'd just order it online.

[image: example of a hole plug]

Comment: Appreciate the info! Are these sorts of hole plugs typically in the plumbing section? Any alternate names they may be called when looking for one?

Comment: Probably in the kitchen/bath section, or near faucet parts. Covering up unused faucet holes is more common than you think. "Hole cover" might be more recognizable. If you live near a particular orange big box store, http://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-Sink-Hole-Cover-in-Stainless-Steel-Finish-89478/203194001 is an example of another design (link provided for reference only).

Comment: "Sink hole cover" will google some examples. Your best bet is the local plumber's supply though. They also come with a threaded rod and wingnut for fastening to thicker counters such as yours.